# How are local environment variables evaluated by Azure Functions with Python runtime?

Tags: python, azure-functions, environment-variables

I understand that...

```
import os

foo = os.getenv('ENV_VAR_NAME')
```

... will pull "environment" variables from the `local.settings.json` file when running an Azure Function locally. This is similar to using a `.env` file.

I know that when deployed to Azure, environment variables are pulled from the Function App's App Settings.

**Question**:

- When running the Function locally, if I have an environment variable set using my terminal (Ex: `set DEBUG=true`), and this variable is **also** included in the `local.settings.json` file (Ex: `"DEBUG": false`), how does the Function code know which env var to pull in?

Comment: Could you please elaborate the question.

Comment: Which part? I'd like to know if I `set DEBUG=true` using the terminal, but have an env setting named `DEBUG` set to `false` in `local.settings.json`, then run a Function locally, which variable does the Function evaluate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK,

In Azure Functions Runtime Context, it evaluates the local environment variables by using the `os` module and the method `os.environ[""]` or `os.getenv("")` and same in the Normal Python Projects.

But in the python projects, python runtime environment evaluates the `.env` file using the library `python-dotenv` for loading the environment variables.

If we define the environment variables in both the files `.env` and `local.settings.json`, Python prefers loading from the file `local.settings.json`in Azure Functions Context:

[image]